# How can create property in c#

Tags: c#, properties

i create property in my project for textbox , but i have a problem with this
........

When i set property *"false"* or *"true"* for TextBox , C# set property *"false"* or *"true"* for all TextBox in the form , what's problem?

**This is My code**

```
public static bool number = false;

public Number_TextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Number_TextBox(IContainer container)
    {
        container.Add(this);

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool IsNumber
    {
        get { return number; }
        set { number = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
        if (IsNumber == true)
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the keyword `static`:

```
public bool number = false;
```

[`static`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) means that your field will be used by the class itself rather than separately for every instance of your class.

Comment: thanks , this is true;

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you are using a `static` variable which effects the entire class. Try changing it to a `private` non-static variable. There's no reason for it to be `public` either, only the properties should be `public`:

```
private bool number = false;
```

Also - you can simplify your code by just writing:

```
public bool IsNumber { get;  set; }
```

Comment: thanks , this is true;

Comment: Read additional note in my answer.